# In database emp table is there i want to create temporary table for the emp table with out using create command

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In database emp table is there i want to create temporary table  for the emp table with out using create command

Comment: Please provide more information. Why do you want to create a temporary table? Why can't you use the create command?

Comment: What do you mean by "temporary table **for** the emp table"? Do you mean you want to create a temp table that is an exact copy of emp? (I don't think that means the temp table is "for" the original table.)

Comment: Also  - sorry, but in Oracle you cannot **create** a temporary table without using the **`CREATE`** command...

Comment: Seriously though, perhaps this old article from AskTom is what you need: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:48812348054

Answer (score 0):

In sql sever, you can do like this:

```
select t1.*
into tempTable
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2
on t1.ParentId= t2.ParentId;
```

Comment: I can see the `oracle` tabs clearly. Where is there any mention of SQL Server in the OP's question, title, or tags? I can't find it.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry about that. I just told how it is possible in SQL SERVER so that he can get any idea or lead to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sql server answers, maybe what you're looking for is [CTAS](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php):

```
create table MY_TABLE as select * from emp;
```

Comment: But... But... `create table` creates a permanent table, not a temporary one; and the OP said explicitly "without using `create` command". Which doesn't make sense, but it does show that the OP has heard of the `create` command...